# ImageView padding inside Gallery

Tags: android, android-widget

If I set padding for ImageView inside gallery like this:

```
imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

it would be set in actual device pixels? How do I set padding programmatically in dip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this..
     `private int mPaddingInPixels;`
       `final float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`
       `mPaddingInPixels = (int) (PADDING_IN_DP * scale + 0.5f);`
     `mPaddingInPixels = mPaddingInPixels + 5;`
     `imageView.setPadding(mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels);`

Comment: Could you explain where does that formula come from? And why do you add 5?

Comment: `0.5` is added so that the number of pixels you get back is always 1 or greater. For instance if the size in pixels was `0.7`, then in integer pixels this would 0 (casting just chops of the decimal points) - nothing would be shown, however if you add 0.5 to you get 0.5+0.7=1.2, which rounds to 1.

Comment: The formula is just `sizeInPixels = dpToPixelScale * sizeInDps` - the extra terms come from converting this floating point result into an integer, doing `a = (int) b` casts `b` to an integer (chops off all the numbers past the decimal point), and the 0.5 is added for the reasons explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I use this unit conversion helper class...

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class UnitHelper {

```
/**
 * Convert dp value to px value
 * @param context The context of operation
 * @param dpValue The dp value to be converted to px
 * @return The px value
 */
public static int dpToPx(Context context, int dpValue) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int)((dpValue * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}

/**
 * Convert px value to dp value
 * @param context The context of operation
 * @param pxValue The px value to be converted to dp
 * @return The dp value
 */
public static int pxToDp(Context context, int pxValue) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) ((pxValue/displayMetrics.density)+0.5);
}
```

}